# Escaping characters in jQuery

Tags: jquery

I've googled and I've checked stackoverflow for an answer, but yet I haven't found a proper one. My input regularly contains `&` (ampersand) and `@` so I would need to escape that variable CN99, how can i do this with jquery?

```
$("#CompanyNameFilter").focus(function() {
    var CN99 = $("#CompanyNameFilter").val();

    $.ajax({
        url: "clients.php?companyname=" + CN99,
        dataType: "html",
        success: function(html) {
            var div = $("#companyList", $(html)).addClass("done");
            $("#companyList").html(div);
        }
    });

});
```

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/332872/how-to-encode-a-url-in-javascript this you check this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should pass the url parameters with the `data` option of `ajax`..

```
$("#CompanyNameFilter").focus(function() {
    var CN99 = $("#CompanyNameFilter").val();

    $.ajax({
        url: 'clients.php',
        data: {companyname: CN99},
        type: 'get',
        dataType: "html",
        success: function(html) {
            var div = $("#companyList", $(html)).addClass("done");
            $("#companyList").html(div);
        }
    });
});
```

This way jQuery will handle the encoding